# Create mssql connection pool in node.js application

Tags: sql-server, node.js, connection-pooling

I am refering to the node-mssql library for my application in node.js using mssql for database connection.
[mssql-ref](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#connection).
I have checked for creation pool of connections, but I found the same for mysql and not for mssql. Please give any reference where I can find sample code snippet for mssql connection pool with node.js.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You would find that information in the page you're referring to yourself. But it's worth noting that the documenting is not explicit about how a Connection pool is created.

```
var connection = new sql.Connection(config);
```

The variable connection here is actually a **connection pool** that still needs to connect...

```
var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
  // ... error checks

  // Query
  var request = new sql.Request(connection);
   // or: var request = connection.request();
  request.query('select 1 as number', function(err, recordset) {
    // ... error checks
    console.dir(recordset);
  });
});
```

Or using promises by omitting a callback argument

```
var connection = new sql.Connection(config);
//connection is actually a connection pool
connection.connect().then(function() {

    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query('select * from mytable').then(function(recordset) {
        // ...
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // ...
    });
}).catch(function(err) {
    // ...
});
```

After you create a single instance of Connection, let all your requests use it like in the example above as opposed to instantiating a new Connection object for each request.

If your asking in relation to a Express 4 web application, see this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356148/how-can-i-use-a-single-mssql-connection-pool-across-several-routes-in-an-express).

Comment: `var connection = new sql.Connection(config);` should read `var connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);`. You'll get an error otherwise.

Comment: Yes, my answer is dated and now incorrect. When I get the chance I'll be sure to update it.