# Node.js require connection inside multiple module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question about the require function of Node.js, imagine we have a module that manages the connection, and many small modules that contain the routes.

An example of connection file: db.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host     : '127.0.0.1',
 user     : 'root',
 password : '',
 database : 'chat'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = connection;
```

and one of the various files to manage the routes:

```
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('./db');

router.get('/save',function(req,res){
 // some code for db
});

module.exports = router;
```

Imagine now to have 20 routes with the same require. How will node.js behave? How many times will my connection be created?

Comment: Good question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356148/how-can-i-use-a-single-mssql-connection-pool-across-several-routes-in-an-express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many times will my connection be created?

There will be *one* connection, because "db.js" runs only once. The things you export get stored (`module.exports`) and that gets returned by every `require("./db")`. To verify:

```
 require("./db") === require("./db") // true
```