# mssql ConnectionPool request() exception NOT A FUNCTION

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I followed this question here using mssql 5.0.4

[How can I use a single mssql connection pool across several routes in an Express 4 web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356148/how-can-i-use-a-single-mssql-connection-pool-across-several-routes-in-an-express)

and I always get the

```
pool.request() is not a function
```

exception. What did I do wrong.

Exactly same 'db.js'

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const config = {/*...*/}

const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
  .connect()
  .then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err))

module.exports = {
  sql, poolPromise
}
```

and the call at:

```
const { poolPromise } = require('./db')

module.exports = {
  get: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const pool = await poolPromise
      // RUNTIME ERROR EXCEPTION at the following line
      const result = await pool.request()
          .query('select * from cars')      

      res.json(result.recordset)
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500)
      res.send(err.message)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: You never declared the pool.request function. On the link you just posted, check `routes/set1.js` file.

Comment: @Rasnick, what do you mean I did not declare the pool.request.  It is under the comment // RUNTIME ...